# Homework project. Can't figure out how sum values via flask_sqlalchemy. Flask tossing 'AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'sum''

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is the problem. I can do count() (the count of this query is 1617) but can't figure out how to do a sum. FWIW, this is from a job satisfaction survey. Lots of 1 and 0 depending on whether they provided a response to a specific question.

This works:

```
@app.route('/list') def list_respondents(): all_working = Jf_Q1.query.filter((Jf_Q1.working==1) & (Jf_Q1.good_job==1)).count() return render_template('list.html', all_working=all_working)
```

This code above works, but what I need to be able to replicate this from postgres:

```
select sum(moderatewellbeing)/sum(good_job) from jf_q1
where working=1
and
good_job=1;
```

I've tried:

```
    all_working = Jf_Q1.query.filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).sum()
    return render_template('list.html', all_working=all_working)
```

But flask tosses me:

```
'AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Here is all my code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import func
from flask_migrate import Migrate
######################################
#### SET UP OUR SQLite DATABASE #####
####################################

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
# Connects our Flask App to our Database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:M1keD8nJ0e@localhost:5432/project2'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app,db)
#####################################
####################################
###################################

# Let's create our first model!
# We inherit from db.Model class
class Jf_Q1(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'jf_q1'

    #########################################
    ## CREATE THE COLUMNS FOR THE TABLE ####
    #######################################

    # Primary Key column, unique id for each puppy
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    respondent_id = db.Column(db.Text)
    good_job = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    mediocre_job = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    bad_job = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    highwellbeing = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    moderatewellbeing = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    lowwellbeing = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    working = db.Column(db.Numeric)

    # This sets what an instance in this table will have
    # Note the id will be auto-created for us later, so we don't add it here!
    def __init__(self,respondent_id,good_job,mediocre_job,bad_job,highwellbeing,moderatewellbeing,lowwellbeing,working):
        self.respondent_id = respondent_id
        self.good_job = good_job
        self.mediocre_job = mediocre_job
        self.bad_job = bad_job
        self.highwellbeing = highwellbeing
        self.moderatewellbeing = moderatewellbeing
        self.lowwellbeing = lowwellbeing
        self.working = working

    # def __repr__(self):

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/list')
def list_respondents():
    # all_working = Jf_Q1.query.filter((Jf_Q1.working==1) & (Jf_Q1.good_job==1)).count()
    # return render_template('list.html', all_working=all_working)
    all_working = Jf_Q1.query.filter(Jf_Q1.working==1).sum()
    return render_template('list.html', all_working=all_working)

    # all_working = select([func.sum(Jf_Q1.working)]).\
    #                 where(Jf_Q1.working==1)
    # return render_template('list.html', all_working=all_working)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:-

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
all_working = session.query(func.sum(Jf_Q1.working)).filter(Jf_Q1.working==1)
```

or also you can use with_entities

```
all_working = Jf_Q1.with_entities(func.sum(jf_Q1.working)).filter(Jf_Q1.working==1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this ASAP and let you know.